# What's the name of # and % in clojure?

Tags: clojure

What is the name of the construct in clojure that uses # at the begining of the expression a % in the middle? For example

```
#(fn [a b] (% b a))
```

I've tried searching the documentation for it but as both characters that define it aren't alphanumeric my search hasn't been too successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a reader macro for the anonymous function declaration. See http://clojure.org/reader for a comprehensive list of reader macros.

For instance, `#(* 5 %)` translates to `(fn [x] (* 5 x))`.

Your example translates in reading phase to `(fn [op] (fn [a b] (op a b)))` (`op` is my choice of placeholder there.)

Answer (score 6):

It appears in (at least) two places:

1. Under [Other Useful Functions and Macros](http://clojure.org/other_functions) (but that doesn't mention %1 %2 etc).
2. In the [Reader](http://clojure.org/reader) (which parses the program) - # causes dispatch to a reader macro via a table lookup (you have to look carefully, but this does describe %1 etc)

In neither case does it have a useful name (actually, "Dispatch" could be the implied name - see second link).  More generally "#" is called [octothorp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign), amongst other things (here in Chile, "gato" (cat) for some unknown reason).

(And yes, %1 %2 are the first and second parameters, etc, while %& is "rest" - you can use just % for the first - see second link).

PS As everyone else has said, it's shorthand for a function.  So `(fn [a b] (+ a b))` is equivalent to `#(+ %1 %2)`:

```
Clojure> (#(println % % %2) 1 2)
1 1 2
nil
Clojure> (#(apply println %&) 1 2 3)
1 2 3
nil
```

Comment: Do %1 and %2 represent multiple parameters?

Comment: %1 and %2 represent the first and second parameters, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The #() construction is shorthand for the definition of an anonymous function. The % sign is used as shorthand for the arguments it takes.

% for the first argument. %integer for multiple arguments (ie %1 %2). %& for the rest (unused) arguments wrapped in a sequence.

```
=> (#(println % %2 %3 %&) 1 2 3 4 5)
1 2 3 (4 5)
```

You can see what function it creates by doing a macroexpand on it

```
#((\ %1 %2) * %2))
=> (macroexpand-1 '#((\ %1 %2) * %2))
(fn* [p1__744# p2__745#] ((\space p1__744# p2__745#) * p2__745#))
```

in normal words the following are the same:

```
  #((\ %1 %2) * %2))
  (fn [p1 p2] ((\ p1 p2) * p2))
```

Be careful to note that your example creates an anonymous function with a new anonymous function inside it.

Answer (score 1):

"#" should be the lambda character, and % represents the first argument expected